# Understanding glimpse() output in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, glimpse

When I run:

```
CO2 %>%
  group_by(Plant, Type, Treatment) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  glimpse()
```

...I see the following output:

```
Observations: 12
Variables: 4
Groups: Plant, Type [?]
$ Plant     <ord> Qn1, Qn2, Qn3, Qc1, Qc3, Qc2, Mn3, Mn2, Mn1, Mc2, Mc3, Mc1
$ Type      <fct> Quebec, Quebec, Quebec, Quebec, Quebec, Quebec, Mississippi…
$ Treatment <fct> nonchilled, nonchilled, nonchilled, chilled, chilled, chill…
$ count     <int> 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
```

...what does the "[?]" signify in the line "Groups: Plant, Type [?]" ?

Why do we not instead see: "Groups: Plant, Type, Treatment" since those are the 3 fields against which we grouped the data?

Comment: I can't reproduce the `[?]`, but I can tell you why you don't see `Treatment` there: after each call to `summarize(...)`, one layer of grouping is "peeled off", leaving only the higher groupings. It's a tricky behavior I often forget is there.

Comment: Not sure why it's displaying as a question mark, but that part of the output should show the number of groups given by `n_groups` (e.g. [12] if there are 12 groups). Note that this is not "number of grouping variables", but the number of actual groups created by the grouping variables. Edit: Actually for me it displays correctly ([12])